# Angular: ng-repeat (possibly $$hashkey) affecting array lookup

Tags: angularjs, service

Im trying to implement a shopping car solution through angular that will enable a customer to select menus items from a list of items displayed within an `<ng-repeat>`. These menu items are represented as objects and I store these list of menu item objects in a shopping cart array. Any time a user clicks on the '+' button I have created, an item in included in the cart order array (or increase the order quantity if it already exist), and the view is updated to also include a '-' button to decrement the order. Thus, implicitly, I have a function that checks whether or not the item in the order array in my cart service. All is fine and good until I refresh the page. The cart is instantiated from a cookie. And the cart has the correct items, but the '-' decrement button does not show up next to items that have been selected in the cart. Below is my code.

**html partial**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <p>
        {{category.items[$index].price | currency}} 
        <a ng-click="menu.addMenuItem(category.items[$index])"> <span class="plus glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        <span ng-show="menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])"> <!-- this does not work on refresh-->
            {{menu.getItemQuantity(category.items[$index])}}
            <a ng-click="menu.subMenuItem(category.items[$index])"> <span class="minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**relevant controller functions**

```
vm = this;
vm.getItemQuantity = function(item){ //always returns 0 on page refresh
    return shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(item);
 };
```

**relevant cart service functions**
    var cart = {};
    cart.order=[];

```
var addItemToOrder = function(item){
    var inOrder=isItemInOrder(item);

    if(inOrder.check){
        cart.order[inOrder.index].quantity+=1;
    }else{
        var orderItem={
            item:item,
            quantity:1
        };
        cart.order.push(orderItem);
    }

    setCartCookie();
};

//always initially returns check property equal to false on page refresh, although cart is instantiated from cookie

var isItemInOrder = function(item){
    for(var i=0; i<cart.order.length; i++){
        if(cart.order[i].item==item){
            console.log('item in order list');
            return {check:true, index:i};
        }
    }
    return {check:false};
};

//more functions
```

It seems like my issues may be due to this thing $$hashkey that gets added as a property to my menu items, but im not sure what to do. Can someone help resolve this. The application works great till the app is refreshed. The menu item on the page does not display a '-' button.

**update**

I have taken a picture from chrome tools and it seems like two identical objects that have been separately instantiated are not equating. Is this normal?
[image: similar objects]

Comment: I'll suggest you read up on `$$hashKey`. That's definitely not what's wrong with the code

Comment: The code is in front of you. Care to share what you think it is?

Comment: The relevant code is not there. What most probably happens is that you're creating objects from what is stored in the cookie, but those objects are not the same as the ones in the displayed list of items.

Comment: @JBNizet I think you are right. I have forced the $$hashkeys to go away but the error persists. I have put up an image in my question from chrome tools outlining the objects. They seem identical. but yes, I am trying to compare an items to those store in a cookie. Do two different object instances never equate?

Comment: No. An object is equal to itself only. Why do you store the whole object in the cookie (which is of a quite limited length)? All you should need is its unique id, and the number of items. Then, on page load, find the matching products in the list by their ID and set their number of bought items.

Comment: @JBNizet oh so two different instance with similar properties cannot be equated? no way!